# CocoonJS and Panda.js - Profile picture type thing possible?

Tags: javascript, ios, cocoonjs

I was wondering if it's possible to use the iPhone camera, take that image, have the user select the face and then crop out that face in CocoonJS and PandaJS. I need to do this to make a profile type thing, but I only want the part of the face that the user selects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CocoonJS is changing his internal architecture to be Cordova compliant. This way, you will be able to use Cordova plugins to access the camera. The cropping and selection of the face could be done using HTML5 and PandaJS. I think this new change will be available in the next weeks. Stay tuned to CocoonJS announcements through their blog or Twitter account.